# Sony Vaio PCG-2J3L won't boot, and no display

Tags: windows-vista, boot, sony-vaio

My friend asked me to look at a Vaio PCG-2J3L Vista Home Premium, which won't boot and the display shuts off after two seconds.

I have determined that the mouse and keyboard work, but as soon as the boot order page is displayed, or entering the BIOS (after pressing the appropriate keys) the screen goes blank. The HDD light blinks and the wireless indicator lights up, then the whole process starts over again.

I have reseated the RAM twice, determined the date and time are correct, (so it's not the MB battery) and tried loading a bootable Vista Home Premium OS System Disk, all to no avail.

I'm almost certain the machine is incapable of booting from `D:` drive, and I can't see the BIOS long enough to make the necessary changes.

Does anybody have any ideas on what I can try next?